# Rogue Number Not Working Python

Tags: python

I have a piece of python code that is supposed to end if a variable is equal to the string 'x', but it doesnt, I dont understand why. Can someone explain please

```
counter = 0
total_price = 0
biggest_price = 0
smallest_price = 10000000000
house_type = 0
while house_type != "x":
    house_type = input("What is the house type? ")
    if house_type != "x":
        number_of_rooms = int(input("How many rooms does the house have? "))
        age = int(input("How old is the house? "))
        price = int(input("What is the houses price? "))
        if price > biggest_price :
            biggest_house_type = house_type
            biggest_rooms = number_of_rooms
            biggest_age = age
            biggest_price = price
    if price < smallest_price :
        smallest_house_type = house_type
        smallest_rooms = number_of_rooms
        smallest_age = age
        smallest_house_price = price
    total_price = total_price + price
    counter = counter + 1
print(biggest_house_type, biggest_rooms, biggest_age, biggest_price)
print(smallest_house_price, smallest_rooms, smallest_age, smallest_price)
print(total_price / counter)
```

Can someone explain why the program doesn't end when X is pressed, and instead just gives house_type the value of 'x'

Comment: Don't you actually want to use `raw_input`?

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Based on the parentheses around `print`, I think he is using Python3.

Comment: You have your input inside of your loop so it's never false

Comment: @zondo sorry, didn't notice that, thanks:)

Comment: @roadrunner66 Sorry it is correct in the code it was just when i was putting it into this i messed that up, i'll try idea now

Comment: There are more issues with indentation. Also logic issues, `if price< smallest:` why adjust the rooms, age etc, if you only know the price is lower than the previous lowest price?

Comment: Did you mean a `rogue` number in your title. Please correct, or post will confuse people.

Comment: @roadrunner66 that was just what out teacher wants us to do, basically, what is is designed to do is tell you what you get from the cheapest house, and I did mean that, it was obviously a typo, I'll correct that shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a number of issues. I tried to make a minimal working example.

```
    counter = 0
    total_price = 0
    biggest_price = 0
    smallest_price = 10000000000
    house_type = ''
    while house_type != "x":
        house_type = raw_input("What is the house type? ")
        if house_type != "x":
            number_of_rooms = int(raw_input("How many rooms does the house have? "))
            age = int(raw_input("How old is the house? "))
            price = int(raw_input("What is the houses price? "))
            if price > biggest_price :
                biggest_price = price
            if price < smallest_price :
                smallest_price = price
            total_price = total_price + price
            counter = counter + 1

            print(biggest_price)
            print(smallest_price)
            print(total_price / counter)
```

Output:

```
What is the house type? 3
How many rooms does the house have? 5
How old is the house? 30
What is the houses price? 100000
100000
100000
100000
What is the house type? 4
How many rooms does the house have? 2
How old is the house? 10
What is the houses price? 200000
200000
100000
150000
What is the house type? x
```

**NOTE**:
If you are on Python 2.x use raw_input(). If you are on Python 3.x use input()

Comment: Beat me to it, please note If  he is on Python 3 he has to  use input() instead of raw_input().

Comment: Yes, I forgot to change that. @Qubesta: please leave your `input` and don't change to `raw_input`, which was necessary for my older version of Python.

Comment: Thanks @roadrunner, I had already learnt about the difference the hard way

Comment: I tried running the code once again before changing it to how you said and it worked, maybe it was a problem with what i was writing it in (wing IDE)